# Simulating remote environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, directory, writable

I'm building a .NET MVC application which will be deployed on a Windows 2003 server. The server has a folder @ c:\Website\Files which needs to be written to from the application.

**How do I cope with this in my development environment so that the MSI setup file, which I will compile, will work correctly when deployed?**

*p.s. the folder is NOT located in a subdirectory of the application project*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another implementation. I think this might be a obsolete question.